# How to attach a git bundle to an existing repository checkout

Tags: git

I got a file.bundle via email. I can unpack it as documented in the manpage ("git clone" on the file in a git-init'ed temp folder). But actually, it's not what I needed. The bundle contains a small extra branch for an existing repo. So it should be simply attached to an existing workdir.

But when I to embed it there, it does not work. I tried to use "git remote add foo " but it cannot fetch from it (usual "not a remote" message). Although .git/config remote entry looks exactly like in the experimental temp checkout's config.

Am I missing something? Is there a sane way to just attach that bundle as as regular remote source? (read-only is sufficient)

Comment: If I understand correctly, your "small extra branch" is a submodule?

Comment: "*`git clone` on the file in a `git-init`'ed temp folder*" This is wrong. It's eiither `git clone` or `git init` + `git pull` but not both.

Comment: @Sorix small extra branch means small extra branch. I have no idea why you start talking about submodules, those are totally unrelated.

Comment: @phd Sounds like the good old mathematician joke. Yes it is wrong (only because it was written down in hurry from memory) and it's not the point.

Comment: @PasterOfMuppets Not the point, that's why I didn't include the note in the answer.

Comment: @phd True, true. Probably I should file a bugreport against that git-bundle manpage. The description of fetching is actually there but this (most useful/most needed) command is buried under lots of other examples for non-ordinary usecases. It's just confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure the file as a remote, you just fetch or pull from it directly. If you fetch to a non-current (for example, a new) branch:

```
git fetch /path/to/file.bundle newbranch:mybranch
```

This fetches branch `newbranch` from the bundle and update (or create a new) local branch `mybranch`.

To update the currently checked out branch (let's name it `master`):

```
git pull /path/to/file.bundle master
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. In addition, I needed a "git bundle unbundle archive.bundle" command before to list the contents inside, to find the exact name of the branch. But now it works, the changeset is properly imported.

Comment: @PasterOfMuppets Use [`git bundle list-heads archive.bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle#Documentation/git-bundle.txt-list-headsltfilegt) to list branches.